# Facebook Authentication access principal

Tags: facebook, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a .net core web API with a custom authentication scheme. Now I am trying to set up a facebook login and access the claims principle created.

The following code works fine with cookies:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie()
    .AddFacebook(config => {
        // appid and secret set up here
        config.CallbackPath = "/externalLogin";
        config.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    });
```

With this code, once I use `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = FacebookDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` on an action, it logs in with cookies and I can access the principal via the `User.Identity` property.

I am trying to get this principal before it is set into the cookie via the sign in scheme. I have set tried setting up a custom scheme for this:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddScheme<ExternalOptions, ExternalLogin>(ExternalLogin.SchemeName, config => { })
    .AddFacebook(config => {
        // appid and secret set up here
        config.CallbackPath = "/externalLogin";
        config.SignInScheme = ExternalLogin.SchemeName;

    });
```

And I have defined my empty classes for scheme yet:

```
public class ExternalOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions { }

public class ExternalLogin : AuthenticationHandler<ExternalOptions>
{

    public const string SchemeName = "External";

    public ExternalLogin(IOptionsMonitor<ExternalOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) 
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {

    }
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        // need to access the principal here
        return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Failed!");
    }
}
```

I try using the debugger on `return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Failed!")` but I don't find property that contains the principal info.

Note: I need to make sure that there are no cookies used to maintain statelessness and in case a client has their cookies blocked (i guess would create an issue). Either ways it isn't considered good to enable cookies on a Web API. Secondly the aim is to set up an external auth that can be later commonly re-used across future external logins as well (such as google and ms).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to access the `ClaimsPrincipal` at various points of the authentification process via the scheme `options.Events` (each scheme defines its own events).

Here, you can use the cookies events. For example:

```cs
services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie(options => 
    {
        // there are various events, be sure to use 
        // the appropriate one for your use case
        options.Events.OnValidatePrincipal = (context) =>
        {
            var principal = context.Principal;

            // reject the principal?
            if (principal.Identity.Name != "MyUser")
                context.RejectPrincipal();

            // each event expect a Task
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    )
    .AddFacebook(config => {
        // appid and secret set up here
        config.CallbackPath = "/externalLogin";
        config.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    });
```